# Can't access C# Controller from Typescript with Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, angular6

I've been working for quite a few months on an Angular 4+ (we're at 6 now) with an ASP.NET Core backend using Visual Studio 2017, but I just couldn't take the amount of errors the VS2017 template would spill out any more. All and all, I always could debug just fine, but that template just won't allow for easy deployment.

Fed up with all of it, I decided to give VS Code a spin, and I was amazed how Angular development works on it. I managed to migrate all my Typescript files to a new project (using `ng new my-project`), and I managed to browse and even publish with no hiccups, but no back-end either. And this is when things got rough. I created another project in VS Code, for the API using `dotnet new -o webapi`, and even though I could migrate all C# code to it and build it successfully, for the life of me I can't call my C# routes from typescript.

For starters, I know that `ng serve` will deploy the angular aplication to port 4200 whereas `dotnet run` deploys the back-end to port 5000, which is a problem in itself, but how do I structure my code in order to run both applications *under the same port*? I don't want to go back to the SPA template (`dotnet new Angular`), which is the only kind of information I'm able to find regarding Angular6 + ASP.NET Core on both VS2017 and VS Code on Google. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-setup-angular-development-environment-in-visual-studio-code/) to set my Angular 6 app in VS Code and it worked marvellously, but I can seem to find a way to create an C# API that it can listen to.

Back in VS2017, I would just have both projects under the same solution, run the web project and everything worked hunky-dory. But now I have no idea how to structure my code in order to do the same under VS Code, I always get a 404 error whenever I try to call an method from the API (which is understandable, since I'm not listening to calls to the back-end at the same port I'm running the front-end application). In summary, I want to migrate the dev environment from VS2017 to VS Code without resorting to the SPA template while I run both front and back-end under the same port (like the template allows me to), but I'm stuck.

Typescript call:

```
this.http.post('/api/lists/GetPack/', { Id: frameList.Id }).subscribe(result => {
  this.pack = result.json();
});
```

C# controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ListsController : Controller
{
    private ListDbContext context;

    public ListsController(ListDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetPack([FromBody]HttpData postData)
    {
        var autoList = new AutoList(context);
        autoList.Load(postData.Id);
        var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(autoList.Pack);
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: _which is a problem in itself, but how do I structure my code in order to run both applications under the same port?_ Simple: Not at all. You tell your angular application where your web application is located. In majority of all cases they run on different ports, domains or subdomains. You can put a reverse proxy before that in production environment and redirect the requests, but this sees not very useful in development. You just need to make sure to enable CORS in your api, so requests from your angular project is allowed

Comment: @Tseng In the end I decided to split them in two ports because you are making too much sense here to be ignored. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same problem like you. I want to deploy my Angular into WebAPI project. So this is what I did.

Step 1: I place WebAPI project and Angular CLI project in a same folder

source

-- WebAPI (.NET Core)

-- WebUI (Angular)

Step 2: edit output of Angular project in Angular configuration:

`"outDir": "../WebAPI/wwwroot/dist"` (.angular-cli.json)

or

`"outputPath": "../WebAPI/wwwroot/dist"` (Angular.json)

Step 3: from WebUI, run `ng build`

Step 4: run WebAPI

Note: you should allow StaticFile in Startup

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Step 5: open http://localhost:5000/dist

And Angular output is running on .NetCore server.

You can remove `dist` folder and use any location you want but it should be in wwwroot

Comment: Thats quite pointless, since you lose all the abilities of angular to do hot module replacement (get an updated webpage by just changing the angular source without restarting) and probably issues with debugging too

Comment: His question is host WebAPI and Angular in a same port. And I think this is a good way. And we can use `ng build --watch`

Comment: Interested to hear how the hot-module replacement code would work when you don't directly connect to the ng instance (it needs to either connect via websockets or fallback mechanism such as longpolling to your ng instance to get notified when the code changes), because you connect via the ASP.NET Core application and w/o hosting / redirecting input/output to and from your application to the ng out of process instance (i.e. using the spa middleware to host ng within the asp.net core app as done in the regular `dotnet new angular` ASP.NET Core angular+webapi templates

Comment: Also on top of that, your setup would load the application from `/dist`, but the api is on `/api` and relative paths would just generate urls like `/dist/api` ... :P

Comment: Thanks @KhaiNguyen, I marked your answer as the solution even though I decided to host the angular app and the web api in two different ports in the end.

Comment: Yes that is correct. All projects I implemented are two ports to host api and angular. But there was one project I had to host in one port